# How to fix the value a html element is being split into multiple html attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm appending a value to an HTML form that is is being generated dynamically using jQuery bu the value is being split into HTML attributes. The value is a sentence. The first word is what is set as the value then the rest of the words are split into HTML attributes.

```
//Here is the sample data being returned

//It's in the URL provided


//Looping through the returned data and dynamically creating a form and append values to it.
          $.each(data.TrainingEvaluationCard['Evaluation_Lines'].Evaluation_Lines, function(key, val) { 
                                        //Append The Table Here Witht the Data
                                        $('tbody').append( '<tr>'+                

                    '<td> <input  class="form-control input-group-md evaluationarea"'+
                            'name="evaluationarea[]"'+
                            'value='+val.Evaluation_Area+''+
                            ' style="font-size: 13px !important; "'+

                            'readonly="readonly"'+
                            'data-validation="required"'+
                            '/>'+
                    ' </td>'+




                    '<td> <input  class="form-control input-group-md evaluationquestion"'+
                            'name="question[]"'+
                            'readonly="readonly"'+
                            'value=' +val.Evaluation_Question+ ''+
                            'style="width: 250px;;"'+
                            '/>'+


                    ' </td>'+
//Here is the result I'm getting

<input class="form-control input-group-md evaluationquestion" name="question[]" readonly="readonly" value="Were" they="" well="" distributed="" around="" the="" class?style="width: 250px;;">
```

I expect the Value of evaluation question to be the whole question being returned not the first word only.

Comment: Can you show what `[ ... ].Evaluation_Lines ` is as data?

Comment: Wrap the value in double quotes: eg `'value="'+val.Evaluation_Area+'" '+`

Comment: You say `//Here is the result I'm getting` but yet i dont even see your `<td>`s. Have you debugged this at all?

Comment: `'value=' +val.Evaluation_Question+ ''+` should be `'value="' +val.Evaluation_Question+ '" '+`

Comment: OP should be advised to break this long (and quote nightmare) up into multiple `+=` declarations.

Comment: Wow, Adding " "  has made it  Work. Thank you!

Comment: Which worked for you @KinyuaJames, two ppl gave solutions

Comment: 'value="'+val.Evaluation_Area+'" ' Worked for me.

Comment: And do you understand that your entire `.each()` call failed because of this?